# Scale rectangles so they have same height and don't exceed a total width?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have three rectangles of different sizes side by side.

I want to scale them all (maintaining their aspect ratio) so they have the same height and don't exceed a total width.

I know I could find the optimal height by trial and error, but I'd like to find a formula that will work no matter what the sizes of the rectangles.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

First, scale them all to the same height (tallest, first, some constant).
Second, add the (new) widths and divide the sum by the desired total width.
Third, scale them all by the inverse of this factor.