# Scale two rectangles so they have the same height and together add up to a fixed total width.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have **two** rectangles of different sizes side by side.

I want to scale them both (each maintaining their original aspect ratio) so they each end up with the same height and together equal a specified, fixed width.

I would like to find a formula that will work no matter what the sizes of the rectangles are (some may be bigger than the target width, some may be smaller - thus some will have to be scaled up and some down).

I found what appears to be a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394911/scale-rectangles-so-they-have-same-height-and-dont-exceed-a-total-width), however the only solution provided seemed to imply a universal scaling factor.  That doesn't work for my situation because the rectangles need independent scaling.  I am also only scaling two rectangles instead of three, and the resulting widths of my rectangles must together add up to a specific width (the other question just didn't want to exceed one).

Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_1, h_2$ be the heights of the rectangles and $w_1, w_2$ be their widths.  Let $w_T$ be the total desired width.  We seek scaling constants $c_1, c_2$ such that when the dimensions of the rectangles are multiplied by $c_1$ and $c_2$, respectively, their heights $c_1 h_1$ and $c_2 h_2$ are equal; moreover, their total width $c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2$ must equal the total desired width $w_T$.  Hence we seek the solution to the system of equations
$$\begin{align}
c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2 &= w_T, \\
c_1 h_1 &= c_2 h_2.
\end{align}$$
The second equation implies $$c_2 = \frac{c_1 h_1}{h_2},$$
so substituting this into the first equation and solving for $c_1$ yields
$$c_1 = \frac{w_T}{w_1 + \frac{h_1}{h_2} w_2} = \frac{h_2 w_T}{w_1 h_2 + h_1 w_2}.$$  This in turn implies
$$c_2 = \frac{h_2 w_T}{w_1 h_2 + h_1 w_2} \cdot \frac{h_1}{h_2} = \frac{h_1 w_T}{w_1 h_2 + h_1 w_2}.$$  These are the desired scaling factors.

Let us put this result into practice.  Suppose the first rectangle has height $h_1 = 5$ and width $w_1 = 3$, and the second rectangle has height $h_2 = 4$ and width $w_2 = 7$.  We want the total width to be $w_T = 9$.  Then the required scaling factors are
$$c_1 = \frac{4(9)}{3(4) + 5(7)} = \frac{36}{47} \approx 0.765957, \quad c_2 = \frac{5(9)}{47} = \frac{45}{47} \approx 0.957447.$$
(Notice the denominators of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the same.)  The resulting scaled rectangles have common height
$$c_1 h_1 = c_2 h_2 = \frac{180}{47} \approx 3.82979,$$
and widths
$$c_1 w_1 = \frac{108}{47} \approx 2.29787, \quad c_2 w_2 = \frac{315}{47} \approx 6.70213.$$
Their total width is $$c_1 w_1 + c_2 w_2 = \frac{108 + 315}{47} = \frac{423}{47} = 9 = w_T.$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  I followed this about 75% of the way just by reading but I will need a piece of paper to decipher the rest of the formula.  I know this is basic stuff for a lot of people, but I am grateful for the straightforward and helpful answer.  I'm new here so I don't know how awards or tipping works, but I am open to being educated.  Let me know if there is something I can do in return.  Thank you again.